# Sequence contains no elements - IList<T> having items

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, generics

```
foreach (var i in Model.Items)
{
        string s = "abc" + i.Name;
}
```

Above code is giving me InvalidOperationException, with message Sequence contains no elements.

Model.Items is of type IList and it contains two elements, despite of that it is giving me exception in the foreach loop.

I applied watch on i.Name, it shows a value, but when the line inside the foreach loop gets executed it gives exception.

What is the issue ?

**Stack Trace**

```
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Country_Hotels_cshtml.Execute() in d:\app\myController\items.cshtml:line 15
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
   at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
```

**Model class**

```
public class ItemsViewModel 
{
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**Lines 1 to 15**

```
@model IPF.Web.Models.ItemsViewModel

@{
    Layout = "_SubLayout.cshtml";
    string desc = "Items of " + Model.Category.Name + ". ";
    string key = "Items of " + Model.Category.Name;
}   

<h1>@string.Format("{0} - Items", Model.Category.Name)</h1>
@if (Model.Items.Count > 0)
{
    IList<Models.Item> items = Model.Items.ToList();//added as suggested
    foreach (var i in items)
    {
        desc += i.Name.ToString() + " ,";//this is where I am getting exception
        //some other stuff
    }
}
```

**Item class**

```
public class Item
{
     [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
     public int Id { get; set; }

     [MaxLength(300, ErrorMessage = "Max length can be 300 only.")]
     [Required]
     [Remote("CheckItemName", "Item", AdditionalFields = "Id")]
     public string Name { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [MinLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Min 50 characters should be entered.")]
     [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
     [AllowHtml]
     [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full")]
     public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**CheckItemName method**

```
public JsonResult CheckItemName([Bind(Prefix = "Item")]Item oItem)
{
    return Json(!repository.Items.Where(c => c.Id != oItem.Id).Any(c => c.Name == oItem.Name), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `i.Name`? Does it work if you do `string s = "abc" + i.Name.ToString()`?; Please click the ["Copy exception detail to clipboard"](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/saraford/WindowsLiveWriter/Didyouknowyoucancopytheexceptiondetailsw_F67C/image_2.png) button and paste the entire exception here by editing your original post.

Comment: i.Name is of type string.

Comment: I guess `i` isn't a good variable name.

Comment: Even if `Items` would be empty you would get no exception in a `foreach`.

Comment: Can you provide more code? What's your Model class, and what about the items?

Comment: What is the actual runtime type of `Model.Items`?

Comment: if Model.Items were empty, the foreach would simply be ignored aswell.

Comment: Have a look at `_Page_Views_Country_Hotels_cshtml.Execute()`. You are using `ENumerable.First` there which throws the exception if there's not at least one element in the sequence.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I am not using ENumerable.First. Besides there are elements in the list. Also before starting the foreach I am checking if (Model.Items.Count > 0)

Comment: Then show us lines 10-20 of `d:\app\myController\items.cshtml` because that is where your problems are.

Comment: Can you include `CheckItemName`'s code too? I think that may be your culperate.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I don't get it, how is CheckItemName method coming into effect here ?

Comment: I don't either but as Holms said *"Once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth."* I have run out of ideas on what could be causing this, from everything I can tell, there is no way `First` could have been called, so I am just shooting in the dark. I don't know MVC at all, but I do see that the `Name` parameter has an attribute that is referencing something called `CheckItemName`, That is the only place left to look as we have rulled out everything else.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, on that note, I have added CheckItemName method. Also, I put a breakpoint at this method, it rightfully doesn't get called when the code in question gets executed. :)

Comment: Are you certain that you're looking at the code that's being executed? For example, *none* of the code you show contains a call to `Enumerable.First` or the `First` extension method of any collection. I doubt that the problem is where you think it is. Perhaps that file used to contain such a call, but you've modified the source and IIS still has the old version cached somewhere?

Comment: I am getting the error since the first time I added the cshtml page.

Comment: @Brij have you attached a debugger to IIS and stepped though it, or are you just going though logs that IIS generates after the fact?

Comment: I am debugging in Visual Studio 2012 and running the MVC 4 app in IIS Express.

Comment: @Brij - I don't see any code where you create the view model and set the Items property on the view model. Can you please provide that controller code?

Answer (score -2):

While working with ASP or MVC + SilverLight, i dont recommend to use First() or FirstOrDefault().

Search .First(); or .FirstOrDefault() and add -> .DefaultIfEmpty();

Comment: `First` and `FirstOrDefault`have perfectly well defined semantics and is very suitable for "ASP" and "MVC + Silverlight" (whatever that is). Adding default if empty just give a different solution and is not suitable for every context.